# How can i create searchfield box with codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I need a search field component but i don't find such a component or a imeoption for text field to make it as search field. i search a lot but still nothing founded.
is there any way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "search field"?

There is a `DataChangeListener` that allows you to track fine grained changes to the `TextField`. You can set a hint & hint icon to show that this is a search field. Its unclear what you are missing.

*Edit based on comments:*

To get the magnifying glass icon instead of Done button on Android you can use the somewhat undocumented flag:

```
textCmp.putClientProperty("searchField", Boolean.TRUE);
```

This is a done event, so you can distinguish pressing this from pressing outside of the field by using the done listener callback on the text component.

Comment: Thank you so much but i dont mean that. i want a textbox field with search mode what i mean is user type some text on it after that he/she fire the search button on the keyboad and searching will be fired. like exactly what we have on android for example define imeoption = actionSearch for a textfield.

Comment: That worked for me, but i can only seach by one the text box: so when i switch from one textbox to another textbox with some other search parameter, the actionListener is triggered without specifying my other search parameter. Can i trigger the search with the 'device search button' which is what i want. Any hint sir?

Comment: Use the setDoneListener() method.